Python requests POST request hangs, when used with websockets library
I'm using Python requests to send a POST request, while concurrently maintaining a WebSocket connection using the websockets library:
import asyncio
import requests
import websockets

async def websocket_handler(uri):
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            print(f"Received message: {message}")

async def make_request():
    s = requests.Session()
    print(1)
    try:
        response = s.post('http://192.168.1.4/create', timeout=10)
        print(3)
        print(response.text)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        print("The request timed out") # this happens
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

async def main():
    websocket_task = asyncio.create_task(websocket_handler("ws://example.com/websocket"))
    request_task = asyncio.create_task(make_request())
    await asyncio.gather(websocket_task, request_task)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

The server logs show no request. The server is reachable and correctly configured. What could be causing this issue when using requests with websockets?

There are 2 problems from looking at the code:

When using while True inside async methods, add await sleep(0.1) to yield back control to the caller.
The requests library is blocking thus it will block the event loop while making requests. There is a good alternative with async support httpx so I suggest you use it instead.


I already tried sleep. I also tried aiohttp but it was still the same.

try using gather without creating tasks, like await asyncio.gather(websocket_handler("ws://example.com/websocket"), make_request())

Below is a working example that includes both the client and server sides (Note: the client side is based on the example given in your question, whereas the server side is based on this answer).
Instead of requests, I would strongly recommend using the httpx library on client side, as requests does not offer an async API, meaning that it actually blocks the event loop when performing HTTP requests, regardless of whether you defined your make_request() function with async def—see this for more details on that. Have a look here, as well as here and here for more details and examples.
It should also be noted that, in your case , you don't necessarily need to use asyncio.create_task() (see Option 3 of this answer for a potential use case on where that function could be useful). Since you are using asyncio.gather(), you could instead pass the awaitable objects, i.e., coroutines (see this answer as well), directly to it, as shown below:
await asyncio.gather(websocket_handler("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws"), make_request())

Working Example
app.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
from websockets.exceptions import ConnectionClosed
import asyncio


app = FastAPI()


@app.post('/create')
async def create():
    return 'success'


@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    try:
        while True:
            await websocket.send_text("test")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
    except (WebSocketDisconnect, ConnectionClosed):
        print("Client disconnected") 

test.py
import asyncio
import requests
import websockets


async def websocket_handler(uri):
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            print(f"Received message: {message}")


# Use `httpx` instead of `requests`, as `requests` within `async def` func() blocks the event loop - see linked answers above
async def make_request():
    s = requests.Session()
    try:
        response = s.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/create', timeout=10)
        print(response.text)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        print("The request timed out")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


async def main():
    # Note: you don't necessarily need `asyncio.create_task()` in this case, see notes above for more details 
    websocket_task = asyncio.create_task(websocket_handler("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws"))
    request_task = asyncio.create_task(make_request())
    await asyncio.gather(websocket_task, request_task)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

